# Get file to load in browser from resources root

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, filepath

I work on Intellij IDEA 2016.3, Java desktop application.

My module structure looks like that :

```
module
  |- resources
     |_ page.html
  |-src
  |-pom.xml
```

I compile projet to .exe by Maven.

I used SWT Browser and I want start with page from resources.

How to get path to this file from resources which can work after compilation ?

I tried load path to `page.html` as below :

```
String pagePath = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("page.html").getFile()).getPath();
```

But after compiling project - it can not find the file. However when running project (without compilation to .exe) - it works well.

How to correct that ?

Comment: Is "resources" dir is on the same level as "src" dir? (by default in a maven project it is src/main/java and src/main/resources)

Comment: and in what directory is the Java class from which you issue the above command? Directly under src or in some subdirectory?

Comment: Src and resources are on the same level

Comment: can you also insert the relevant parts of your pom.xml? (compilation and exe creation)

Comment: Basic, nothing specialy. But as I wrote in my question it return me path but can get path from compiled file, Browser is loaded from Url so there is a problem - bad path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I solved it by loading `page.html` content as HTML and load it on browser by `browser.setText(htmlPageContent)`

Answer (score 3):

The Maven convention is to place static web resources (html, css, js, images, etc) within /src/main/webapp.  Refer to the standard directory layout here: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Comment: So You say that I need to do not put it in resources but in other source ? Loading the browser looks that firstly find file, second get path of them and load browser with this path (as You type path in textfield to url in browser) or maybe there is better way to load page - not to load own created from path file.

Comment: If you're building a web application (packaged as a war file, or as an executable jar with an embedded web container) and you're using Maven, place your web resource files, such as html or css files, underneath the /src/main/webapp folder. After building, your resources will be available using a web browser. For example, if you add /src/main/webapp/myFolder/foo.html, then after install and running the webapp, you would be able to see that in a browser at http://server:port/myFolder/foo.html

Comment: I build a desktop application with load SWT Browser and own created page.